# Measuring Geodesic Distance in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, measurements, geodesic

I'm working with only a basic/student license for ArcGIS 10.1 on an ocean mapping project.

I've created a grid that covers all ocean area, capturing various characteristics within that grid (the grid is now in point data).

I now need to add the distance from each point to the edge of various polygons (shipping lanes, countries) but need geodesic distance because of the large distance covered.

I read that if you keep the data in a geographic coordinate system, unprojected, the distances generated through various measuring tools in ArcGIS automatically measure in geodesic.

Is this true, and if not, is there a way to force geodesic measurements in various tools?

Comment: Yes, keep the coordinate system unprojected (geographic) and the calculated distances will be on the referenced ellipsoid - geodesic

Comment: You'll need to qualify which "various tools" you'll be using, since getting geodetic measurements may not be possible with all tools.

Comment: I agree with @Vince - can you let us know a particular tool that you are wanting to use, have tried, and think may not be using geodetic measurements, please?  Asking about multiple tools in the one question would make this too broad.